# Converting PHP Curl to Python request

Tags: python, php

This code is in PHP to call a curl post request with some header and data.

```
<?php

    $api = 'someapi';
    $method = 'somemethod';
    $api_path = "someurl";
    $data = array(
        'start_datetime' => '2021-07-15 13:00:00',
        'end_datetime' => '2021-07-15 13:20:00',
        'token' => 'sometoken' // token from file
    );
    
    $params = array(
        "api"=> $api, 
        "method"=>$method, 
        "data"=> json_encode($data)
    );
    
    $secure_key = "somesecret";

    $header = array();
    $header[] = 'SECUREKEY:'.$secure_key;

    // call curl
    $__curl_handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($__curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $api_path);
    curl_setopt($__curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($__curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
    curl_setopt($__curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($__curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
    curl_setopt($__curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

    $response = curl_exec($__curl_handle);
    $errno    = curl_errno($__curl_handle);
    $errmsg   = curl_error($__curl_handle);

    $result_arr = array(
        'response'=>$response,
        'errno'=>$errno,
        'errmsg'=>$errmsg
    );

    curl_close($__curl_handle); 

    echo $result_arr['response'];

?>
```

Now i need to do the same in a python project. Since I am new to Python May i request some help doing this?

This is my try:

```
    api = 'someapi'
    method = 'somemethod'
    api_path = "someurl"
    data = {
        'start_datetime' : '2021-07-15 13:00:00',
        'end_datetime' : '2021-07-15 13:20:00',
        'token' : 'sometoken' // token from file
    }
    
    params = {
        "api": api, 
        "method":method, 
        "data": json.dumps(data)
    }
    
    secure_key = "somesecret";

    header = {
        "SECUREKEY":secure_key
    }

    response = requests.post(api_path,
                            data=params,
                            headers=header)

    print(response.json())
```

But its not working as expected. How to do this?

Comment: Explain what do you mean by "But its not working as expected". print `response.status_code `

Comment: I meant, API side it is not receiving the query data

Comment: @AjuJohn you are using `data=query` but your data is params, not query. Try `data=params`

Comment: Are you able to run the query using a tool like postman? If you can - postman can generate the python code for you.

Comment: @user56700 Sorry, that was a typo, while adding the question on stackoverflow

Comment: @AjuJohn what is the result, when you run it? What status code and response is returned?

Comment: @balderman It will be helpful. Let me try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For any `cURL` request best tool for testing is [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) and it is free.
You can make request with graphic interface and you can convert it to any code language (also Python) by clicking on `</>` icon

[image]

I also code in PHP but i believe that this will be working Python code for you

```
import requests

url = "someapi_url"

payload={'start_datetime': '2021-07-15 13:00:00',
'end_datetime': '2021-07-15 13:20:00',
'token': 'sometoken'}
files=[

]
headers = {
  'SECUREKEY': '--SECUREKEY_VALUE--'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```